# If a carry-on luggage is placed in the baggage hold, is the passenger entitled to some compensation?

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage, compensation

Sometimes flight attendants force passengers to put their carry-on luggage in the baggage hold, in case there is no more space in the cabin. In that situation,  is the passenger entitled to some compensation?

Comment: compensation for what? Damage to the bag or contents? Personal harm because you didn't have access to medications? Loss of contents?

Comment: @mkennedy I was wondering as I wasn't sure whether the purchased flight ticket gives a guaranteed or a possible space for carry on luggage.

Comment: What airline and what country? Hypothetical question or one based on experience? I have flown a significant amount and never seen that happen. AND it would mean the bag had to be checked to ensure it contained no materials that were no allowed in checked luggage. (eg most batteries and all Lithium batteries). And there are security issues. None of which a flight attendant would be expected to be qualified to be responsible for.  I've heard of airlines where you can cram almost anything into carryon as long as the roosters don't crow, but usually size and weight of carryon is well controlled.

Comment: Based on experience eg happened twice to me this month in the US (I tend to board late). Jetblue and American Airlines.

Answer (score 2):

No.

There is no right (for you as a passenger) to have carry-on luggage; and as safety of the aircraft is paramount, having no place to stow luggage in the cabin is a risk - as it can turn any item into a projectile if there were turbulence.

So the airline is well within their right to stow the luggage in the cargo hold.

Further, many times if this is the case - the luggage is provided to you at the jet-bridge/staircase on arrival.

If you have some medication or other such items in your carry on and you are asked to stow it in the cargo hold; you should remove these items (for obvious reason).

---

Now, if the airline has a specific fee for carry-on luggage (that is you have to pay for this privilege) then you might be liable for some compensation.

Although, I don't know of any airline that does, but you can never assume things - especially with LCC (low cost carriers).

Comment: Do you then agree that the flight personnel need to be trained to handle security & safety issues re what can and cannot be safely or properly transferred to the cargo hold?

Comment: No as this is the job of the baggage handlers and the load master.

Comment: I have had gate checked luggage returned on the baggage carousel, and yes, my lovely leather backpack had gotten some smears of whatever in the process. (And not even mentioning fear about the risk of delicate items transported within being damaged.)

Comment: Some say leather with smears gives it character ;) - however I can appreciate that luggage does get manhandled a bit.  Luckily I have not yet experience this - short of having a few wheels popped off of luggage (which I didn't mind) - and one bag being lost in over 15 years of traveling - I can say I am lucky.